# How do I add a graphic overlay on an activity? Android

Tags: android, android-activity, overlay

I am trying to have a picture show up in the middle of the screen guiding people what to press (eg an arrow to a button). What do I use so that the arrow design will show up at the appropriate spot and dissapear after I do something (like press the screen)

Thanks!

EDIT
Here is the xml layout for one of my activities, note the imageview at the bottom, it shows the picture in the front

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp" android:background="@drawable/mytitlebackground" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnAddFriends"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></ImageButton>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/imTracking" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>

<Button android:id="@+id/btnUpdateLocation" android:text="Update Location"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></Button>
<ImageButton android:src="@drawable/mapbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btnMaps"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnUpdateLocation"></ImageButton>
<ImageButton android:text="Refresh"
    android:src="@android:drawable/stat_notify_sync" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnRefresh" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></ImageButton>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_above="@+id/btnUpdateLocation" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/imtrackinglistview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/iVImtrackingpopup" android:layout_width="300dp" android:layout_height="330dp" android:src="@drawable/imtrackinghelp_en" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></ImageView>
```

When I try to "click" the relative layout to make the image invisible, it doesn't work unless I click the top of the layout

```
RelativeLayout Imtrackingrelativelayout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutImtracking);
    Imtrackingrelativelayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ImageView imtrackingoverlay=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iVImtrackingpopup);
            imtrackingoverlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the image centre aligned and put click listener over root layout and on click make this image invisible......Better to use relative layout for this.....

Comment: Great Idea! I will try this out tomorrow morning!

Comment: So Im trying to put this over a listview but the image is showing up behind it, how do I determine the order of the images

Comment: I have edited the question to show my xml, thanks for helping me out

Comment: unable to see your relative layout with id relativeLayoutImtracking. Assuming it is your root layout. Make sure it has height set as fill_parent. Please check there must be something wrong in the layout property else share your full xml code...

Comment: sorry, here it is again. There is a listview underneath the images that also accepts button clicks, so when I click on the picture it doesn't go away and instead clicks on the item of the listview. The message only goes away when I click another part of the screen (ie the top or bottom)

Comment: your items are put over layout and you are putting click listener over layout and it will work on the layout and not on the items put over layout ...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the **ShowcaseView** library? It offers a more cleaner approach to what you are trying to achieve

Check out the project here:-

https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView